# Multiple different attachment types per model using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Within my Rails app, I have a Post model. A post has three different attachment types, an image, song, or video.

Here is what I have in my model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :image, styles: {
    large: '900x900>'
  }

  has_attached_file :song
  has_attached_file :video

  # Validate the attached image is image/jpg, image/png, etc
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  validates_attachment_content_type :song, :content_type => [ 'application/mp3','application/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ],
            :message => 'Please select a .mp3 file'

  validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ['video/mp4'],
    :message => "Sorry, right now we only support MP4 video"

end
```

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
def create_new_post
    @post = Post.new
    @post.image = params[:image]
    @post.save
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Here is what I have in my schema for my posts table:

```
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
t.string   "song_file_name"
t.string   "song_content_type"
t.integer  "song_file_size"
t.datetime "song_updated_at"
t.string   "video_file_name"
t.string   "video_content_type"
t.integer  "video_file_size"
t.datetime "video_updated_at"
```

I am using a `form_tag` to create a post. Not all attachments are required to create a post. Upon submitting my form I am getting this error:

```
undefined method `song_content_type' for #<Post:0x007fa704a54b70>
```

What is causing this and how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `validates_attachment_content_type :song` to work you need to have a `song_content_type` attribute defined on your `Post` model (`posts` table).

Your `schema.rb` should contain something like this:

```
create_table "posts" do |t|
  t.string   "song_file_name"
  t.string   "song_content_type"
  t.integer  "song_file_size"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yup, I have that in my schema.

Comment: And the `schema.rb` actually matches the database? And you have restarted the server?

Comment: Yup, the schema is matches the db and I have restarted the server.

Comment: Btw, does the `Post.new.song_content_type ` work? If it fails the something is wrong with the schema, if not then with the paperclip.

Comment: Post.new.song_content_type does not work, why could this be? I don't see anything wrong with the schema

Comment: Can the order in my post model make a difference?

Comment: Does the `p Post.column_names` contain the `song_content_type `?

Comment: No, it does not. How is that possible? Why would it show in my schema file?

Comment: Check whether the column is actually in the table: `Post.connection.execute "select * from posts limit 1;"`. If the result hash doesn't contain the column then look on your database, something is wrong there.

Comment: Thank you sooooooooooooooo much. Just fixed it. There was something wrong with my database.